# Google Admin SDK Directory API .Net Quick start guide

Tags: .net, google-directory-api

I am looking to explore the Google Admin SDK Directory API. Is there a Quick start guide or tutorial available.
I have looked at the documentation there are quick start guides for java and python but not .Net. 
I help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step is to have a Service account with Domain-Wide Delegation Authority.
The link below shows how to
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation

It say to add the service account to the "Manage third party OAuth Client access" in advanced setting but i had "Manage OAuth Client access" that works as well

```
String serviceAccountEmail = "......@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\key.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
                {
                    Scopes = new[]
                    {
                        DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryUser
                    },
                    User = "admin@domain.com"
                }.FromCertificate(certificate));

                var ser = new DirectoryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "Get it to work",
                });

                User newuserbody = new User();
                UserName newusername = new UserName();
                newuserbody.PrimaryEmail = "jack@domain.com";
                newusername.GivenName = "jack";
                newusername.FamilyName = "black";
                newuserbody.Name = newusername;
                newuserbody.Password = "password";

                User results = ser.Users.Insert(newuserbody).Execute();
```